# Mongodb Atlas Connection String Does not work with Zapier

Tags: mongodb, zapier, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to create a zapier job (zap) that involves creating a document in a mongodb collection each time a new row is added to a spreadsheet.

To achieve this, I need to connect Zapier to MongoDB. However, the connection string that is provided in MongoDB Atlas (which I've used successfully to connect other apps) doesn't seem to work with Zapier.

In the connect dialog box (https://ibb.co/Tq1LXYf), I've tried entering my mongodb connection string as the host (without password and user name, which have to be entered separately).

mongodb+srv://:@cluster0-v1yap.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Zapier can't connect, and it returns the error message:

cluster0-v1yap.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname

Would anyone be able to tell me where to get the correct value for the host field in the Zapier connection pop-up(see screenshot linked above)?

Comment: I believe your host should be `cluster0-v1yap.mongodb.net`, based on the information you provided.

Comment: Thanks. I did try that as well, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: The port must be given separately like the form requests. Do not specify it in the hostname.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few months, but MongoDB support told me:

> We have been in contact with Zapier in the past, and they have let us know that the current MongoDB connector is moving to deprecated status and a new MongoDB connector is under development which will support current versions of MongoDB. They were not able to give us a timeline, perhaps the folks at Zapier would be able to provide you with more information so I would encourage you to get in contact with Zapier Support.

This is the workaround they suggested.

> Another approach you could take would be to use MongoDB Atlas' [Stitch serverless](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/stitch) platform (included with your Atlas cluster) to create a simple API endpoint, which you could then call using [Zapier's Webhook Integration](https://zapier.com/apps/webhook/integrations#triggers-and-actions).

Comment: I'll have to try that as it looks like that mongodb connector is not reliable. Thanks.